# How to setup Linkedin Autentication with dotnetopenauth on mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

I am create a new asp.net website and I need to use a few authentication provider. I easily got all the providers working (thanks to this awesome template and scotts vid). I'm a little stuck with getting this to work with a linked in account. I assume it would be just as easy as it was for face book but I can't find any tutorials or snippets. I'm sure I'm not the first guy to try this. Please assist

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/) or [this](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1190)?

Comment: I have seen the 1st one but I figured that there was a much easier solution. I'll look at the 2nd solution now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AuthConfig class under the RegisterAuth method call the method

`OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterLinkedInClient("xxxxx","xxxxxxx");`

with the appropriate inputs you receive from LinkedIn. Also another thing, I received an error when trying to log in using linkedin. I came across a post on stack overflow(wish I can give the link), you need to update
dotnetopenauth, I used nuget to update it. Thanks PinnyM.